# How to customize validates_length_of message to include attribute length?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to customize the error message on a `validates_length_of` to include the length of the attribute being checked.  I know we can do `"%{value}"` or `"%{attribute}"` within the message to get those values. Is there a flag we can use to get the length of the attribute?  I was hoping to avoid creating a custom validation just to get a pretty message.  Additionally, it seems a waste to do count twice on a string when the validator is already doing it.

Here is what I would like:

```
validates_length_of :a, :b,:c, :d, :e, :maximum => 1000, :message=>"is to long, maximum length is` %{count}, current length is %{actual length here} "
```

Comment: Not calling this an answer because it's more of stab in the dark, but how about :message => "length should be %{count} but should be #{%{value}.length}".  Basically, I'm hoping that you can treat %{value} like a real expression inside #{}.

Comment: danh, that was one of my first thoughts.  Unfortunately it did not work as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Proc to get the attributes

```
validates_length_of :a, maximum: 1000,
    message: proc { |p, v| "is to long, " +
                           "maximum length is #{v[:count]}, " +
                           "current length is #{v[:value].length}" }
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid the proc.  But after digging in the rails source, I don't think what I was hoping for exists.